# Question regarding conjugation of two verbs with a (-たい）ending

Tags: grammar, translation

Learning Japanese on my own so i will be using this site as i means to practice and have some questions answered! If you provide the answer in Kanji, if you coul dplease put also the furigana (no romanji) i would appreciate it ! Thank you!

My question is, i want to make the sentence:

"I thought you didn't want to see me"

I want to use the word あう（to meet) and 思う

Would i  conjugate あう as あいたくない and then add おもっている　？

how do i link those two verbs? I was thinking first use the の particle to make あう a noun, but that wouldn{t make sense.

Don{t think i could use the　て form since i want to say i want.

Can someone please help me with the translation and how you got to do it? Both polite and informal ways please :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use のだ form when you express what you have judged from situations.
i.e. 会いたくないのだと思った.

(会いたくなかったのだと思った basically means "I thought you had not wanted to see me", but you can use it for "I thought you didn't want to see me" too.)

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Firstly, you are correct that you treat the ～たい form like an i-adjective. So "You didn't want to meet" would be 会いたくなかった. Then, the construction for "I thought X" is 「X」と思った。 So, putting those together, "I thought you didn't want to meet me" becomes 会いたくなかったと思った, although I honestly can't say how common such a sentence would be in Japanese.

Alternatively, you might say something like 会【あ】いたくない気【き】がした, which is like "I had a feeling / I got the impression you didn't want to see me".

Comment: 会いたくない気がした would be interpreted as "I didn't feel like seeing you"...

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Is there a more appropriate phrase for the meaning I was trying to convey?

Comment: (^ ごめん、コメントに気づかんかった・・・) How about... 「会いたくないんだな、と思った。」「会いたくないんだろうな～って思った」とか。。 or depending on the context.. 「会いたくないだろうなって思った」とか「会いたくないのか(な)と思った」とか。。

Comment: ありがとう！ I often get mixed up in phrases that have some back-and-forth of actors, so thanks for your suggestions.